# CSS: Display icon next to text of link on mobile sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aerra/0og26caj/49/)

I want to show an icon next to all links. **It's important to note that I am limited to CSS, so I cannot change the HTML structure**. I guess a JS solution could work, but seems over the top? I'm hoping there's another CSS solution I just haven't thought about.

I am using `inline-block` on an `<a href="/">`, and I am adding an `:after` element on it, which is supposed to be an icon.

On bigger screen sizes the links are fine. However, on mobile, you can see that the `"download here a pdf..."` link is being cut off from the text and the link is not at the end of text.

I realise *why* this is happening: The link has `inline-block` and the `:after` element has `position: absolute; right: 0;`.

What I'm having trouble with is figuring out *how* to approach this differently so that the link stays `inline` while also having a space to the right in order show the icon.

[image]

Comment: you can use media queries to change your style completely depending on the situation.

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2a8pz36r/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```css
body {
     font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
}
 ol {
     border: 1px solid;
}
 ol.mid {
     width: 420px;
}
 ol.min {
     width: 320px;
}
 ol.max {
     max-width: 720px;
}
 a {
     color: inherit;
     display: inline;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     position: relative;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding-right: 10px;
}
 a:after {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 9px;
     height: 9px;
     background-color: orange;
     border: 1px solid red;
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
     left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h4>320px</h4>
<ol class="min">
  <li>
    This is a numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is a longer numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto two whole lines and also has a <a href="/">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto three whole lines lorem ipsum <a href="/">download here a pdf consetetur sadipscing elitr</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  </li>
</ol>

<h4>420px</h4>
<ol class="mid">
  <li>
    This is a numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is a longer numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto two whole lines and also has a <a href="/">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto three whole lines lorem ipsum <a href="/">download here a pdf consetetur sadipscing elitr</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  </li>
</ol>

<h4>720px</h4>
<ol class="max">
  <li>
    This is a numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is a longer numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto two whole lines and also has a <a href="/">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto three whole lines lorem ipsum <a href="/">download here a pdf consetetur sadipscing elitr</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  </li>
</ol>
```

The SASS code:

```
body {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ol {
  border: 1px solid;
  
  &.mid {
    width: 420px;
  }
  
  &.min {
    width: 320px;
  }
  
  &.max {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 10px;
  
  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using absolute positioning it then takes your after pseudo object out of the document flow, but what you want I think is to have it in the flow, then it's always at the end of the line without having to do much more than use display: inline-block and a little margin and vertical alignment. See the below, this works:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ol {
  border: 1px solid;
}
ol.mid {
  width: 420px;
}
ol.min {
  width: 320px;
}
ol.max {
  max-width: 720px;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 0 2px 5px;
  /* position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%); */
}
```

```html
<h4>320px</h4>
<ol class="min">
  <li>
    This is a numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is a longer numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto two whole lines and also has a <a href="/">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto three whole lines lorem ipsum <a href="/">download here a pdf consetetur sadipscing elitr</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  </li>
</ol>

<h4>420px</h4>
<ol class="mid">
  <li>
    This is a numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is a longer numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto two whole lines and also has a <a href="/">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto three whole lines lorem ipsum <a href="/">download here a pdf consetetur sadipscing elitr</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  </li>
</ol>

<h4>720px</h4>
<ol class="max">
  <li>
    This is a numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is a longer numbered list
  </li>
  <li>
    This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto two whole lines and also has a <a href="/">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  This is such a long long long numbered list that it wraps right round onto three whole lines lorem ipsum <a href="/">download here a pdf consetetur sadipscing elitr</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: the only problem with this code is the fact that "download here ..." link is not inline with the text.

Comment: @Aerra you are correct, thanks! I have fixed that by removing inline-block from a {}